# Integrating IIB with IBM Transformation Extender

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

Bar file deployment (which uses java nodes) is failing for me on Linux machine because one of its dependent library uses ITX  nodes.

Installing IBM Transformation Extender run time (ITX 9) on Linux machine does not resolve the issue.

The deployment is done using IIB toolkit from windows as well as command line deployment.

What configuration changes have to be done so that IIB is able to find the ITX dependencies ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : I remember now, you need to load the DTXENV in your profile.(See related IBM APAR about this : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI63209 in case you already did and still have issues). In my case, this is the line I had to put in my profile :

```
. /app/iib/wsdtx/wmqi/dtxwmqi_900_64.sh
```

Other possible issues : installation issue or license agreement not accepted.

Comment: There is also package called "IBM Transformation Extender for integration servers". Is this required? where can i find this package for x86 architectures.

Comment: You indeed need the specific ITX package for Integration Server. The "regular" ITX installation won't be used by IIB. You can find it for all the OS at the same place on IBM website. It is the same package you need to install on your workstation to have ITX nodes in the IIB toolkit (but for unix instead of windows in your case)

Comment: I searched the packages, but could not find linux package for x86 architecture.If you find the link, please share

Comment: Based on the compatibility page, the package is the same for x64 and x86 system (on Unix at least). I could easily download it from ibm passport advantage. You can find the detail of the compatibility here : https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=D59D8700BB8611E499F1528B5A128231&osPlatform=Linux